# customContextMenu click does not register in mouseEvent

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

When requesting a context menu, I'm trying to register a mouseReleaseEvent when the context menu is opened (same as with left click). However, when the context menu is called, no mouse event is triggered. There is a workaround by calling `right_click_select` in `context_menu` but I'm sure there's a proper Qt way of doing this. I'm also able to manually call mouseReleaseEvent but without the event defined, it throws an argument error.

Main:

```
self.dataTree = TreeView(self)
self.dataTree.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.dataTree.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.dataTree.context_menu)
```

TreeView class:

```
class TreeView(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        QTreeView.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

    def right_click_select(self, pos):
        item = self.indexAt(pos)
        if item.isValid():
            pass
        else:
            self.clearSelection()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print("right click release not received here")

    @pyqtSlot(QPoint)
    def context_menu(self, pos):
        if indexes := self.dataTree.selectedIndexes():
            # Below is the workaround
            self.dataTree.right_click_select(pos)

            # Workaround no. 2, argument error without event
            self.mouseReleaseEvent()

            menu = QMenu()
            menu.exec_(self.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos))
```

Comment: The question what is the goal, seems to me to be an XY problem.

Comment: I ended up just moving everything about click handing to a separate function and calling it from both mouseReleaseEvent and context_menu with pos and optionally event as arguments. Initially I wanted both left an right clicks select the item and do stuff based on selection, with the right click additional opening the context menu.

Comment: @misantroop the behavior changes depending on the OS (right button press or release), but if the event is handled for the menu, no mouseRelease is then relayed to the original widget (and, I'd say, for good reasons, imagine if the widget was removed due to an action of the context menu *before* the mouse was released). You can "synthesize" the event if you need it, or create an independent function that is called both from the mouse release *and* the context menu events. See the linked question.